# webpack dev server failed to startup, no error in terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gulp

I fork from this repo from my friend
https://github.com/eldyvoon/wa-clone/tree/release

I run `npm run spa-server` which run the gulp task to fire up webpack dev server. It did launched successfully, it doesn't have any error in my terminal, but I can't open http://localhost:5000

Any clue? I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

The express server is running on port 4000
[image]

Comment: I don't no problem running express server at port 4000. check the code again, there are 2 server, express server is fine but webpack-dev-server for front end app is suppose to be running at port 5000.